# Can you view the default Vim settings?

Tags: vim

I’m starting to learn about creating my own `.vimrc` file and I keep noticing features that are missing with my custom version that were present in the default setup.

I was wondering if it is possible to view the default settings, so I can compare them to my own and look up all the standard inclusions I don't know to learn more about them.

I searched and couldn’t find an answer online, and if the reason why there isn’t one is that the answer to this question is glaringly obvious, I’m really sorry; I’m still a bit of a noob :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No worries, it’s a perfectly valid question. Unfortunately, the answer is a bit complicated. First of all, Vim has certain defaults that are documented in the built-in help system.

Some of them are only used when Vi compatibility mode is disabled, and that’s the first customisation most people make:

```
:set nocompatible
```

On top of that, many distributions provide their own custom config, for example Debian/Ubuntu comes with `/etc/vim/vimrc`. To makes things even more confusing, Vim 8 comes with a sane configuration (called `default.vim`) that only gets applied when `~/.vimrc` is not found. Not to mention that NeoVim comes with its own set of defaults.

In practice, I suggest to explicitly set any options you care about to make sure your config is portable between systems and versions of Vim. To see the current value of a given option, use a question mark:

```
:set showcmd?
```

To learn more about a given option (including the default value), use Vim’s comprehensive help system:

```
:help showcmd
```

Finally, you might want to check [my annotated `.vimrc`](https://github.com/adambyrtek/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) for some inspiration, and there is also the [vim-sensible plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible) that provides some sane defaults most people would agree to.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to see “vanilla” Vim options is to start it using:

```
$ vim -u NONE -N
```

It will start Vim without any of your customizations or plugins, but still in ‘nocompatible’ mode (i.e., basically, running full-fledged Vim, instead of its stripped down version emulating Vi).

Then, you can execute the following commands:

```
:set all
:map
:command
:let
:function
:autocmd
```

to see all options, mappings, commands, variables, functions, and auto-commands, respectively, that are currently in effect. (I cannot promise I haven’t forgotten a customization category.)

Vim also comes with a bunch of basic configurations that is skipped by the `-u NONE` option, that you can also include while still excluding your `.vimrc`, by using `-u NORC`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Amadan's answer, I came up with this file (`ShowAllDefaults.vim`) and command to run it and capture the output.

.  In the mean time, learning that, if you have files under `~/.vim`, they get executed if you use this:

```
vim -u ShowAllDefaults.vim -N +q
```

So the correct way to do it is:

```
vim -u NONE -N +"source ShowAllDefaults.vim" +q
```

Contents of ShowAllDefaults.vim:

```
set verbosefile=/tmp/ShowAllDefaults.log
set all
map
command
let
function
autocmd
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying after long time to get familiar with vim also, and I came across this because I had same question.

How I found answer from within vim was to pull up help on defaults and it explained to get defaults along with .vimrc for newer users and also gave the path to default script so you could open it right up in your editor and read & compare it.

I am not going to give my exact path because that might change in different versions, so best to get it from help documents inside vim.